# Какой аналог ctrl+k+d в visual studio на маке?

Tags: visual-studio, macos

В виндовсе ctrl+k+d выравнивает весь код. Но это комбинация не работает на маке. А какая комбинация клавиш работает?

Comment: [Стандартные сочетания клавиш в Visual Studio для Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/mac/keyboard-shortcuts?view=vsmac-2019)

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + i выравнивает весь код в visual studio на маке. Если кому нужно будет